# How t add Gesture inside XAML from code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, key-bindings

So i have this `KeyBinding`:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+Alt+S" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
                HotkeyManager.RegisterGlobalHotkey="True" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

And my application have several `ToggeButtons` that the user need to specify the shortcuts ans i want to be able to change this from code behind:

```
Gesture="Ctrl+Alt+S"
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You could bind as demonstrated here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2009/10/29/new-wpf-features-keygesture-binding/

Answer (score 0):

Create a `KeyGesture`. The `ModifierKeys` is a flag `enum`:

```
KeyBinding binding = new KeyBinding()
{ 
    Gesture = new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Alt) 
};
```

Comment: and how to add it into my application ? this key will work in the background ?

Comment: @falukky: You'll add a `KeyBinding` to `this.InputBindings` of the window.